# KeyError when trying to extract JSON string

Tags: python, json

I'm getting a `KeyError` with my below code. Other solutions I could find didn't work.

I'm using requests to make an API call. It returns the following JSON:

```
{"status":200,"msg":"OK","result":{"url":"https:\/\/redacted\/something","valid_until":"2019-10-13 12:34:56"}}
```

I only need the URL in this JSON but I cannot seem to get this working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import json

url = 'https://redacted'
user = 'redacted'
api_token = 'redacted'

r = requests.get(url)

r_dict = r.json()

print(r_dict['url'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL is inside the `result` dict.

```
print(r_dict['result']['url'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to decode your JSON string with

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json

json_in = '{"status":200,"msg":"OK","result":{"url":"https:\/\/example.com\/something","valid_until":"2019-10-13 12:34:56"}}'

json_stuff = json.loads(json_in)

# debugging only print(json_stuff.keys())
print(json_stuff['status'])
print(json_stuff['msg'])
print(json_stuff['result'])
print(json_stuff['result']['url'])
print(json_stuff['result']['valid_until'])
```